# How to import csv files of a directory

Tags: r, for-loop, append

I have 7 files in my directory, I am trying to import all of them dynamically. I am using the following code:

```
file <- dir(getwd(),full.names=TRUE)    
for (i in 1:length(file)){
  file_i <- read.csv(file[i],stringsAsFactors = F)
}
```

Above code is not working as we have to define the new variable outside the `for` loop. Can anybody suggest me a way?

Comment: Probably just `files <- lapply(file, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (untested). Then you'll have a list with all the files which you can select data sets from or collapse it into one data set (if all have same column names) using something like `DF <- do.call(rbind, files)`

Comment: Or we can read the files with `fread` from `data.table`.  `library(data.table); files <- lapply(file, fread)` and then convert to a single dataset if needed `DT <- rbindlist(fread, idcol=TRUE)`.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r .

Comment: @maj  Your suggestion already has been taken into account.